# Sphinx warning: Unknown interpreted text role "method"

Tags: python, python-sphinx

When running:

```
$ make html
```

I get:

```
...
/home/app_dir/app1/forms.py:docstring of app1.forms.SomeForm.some_method:3: ERROR: Unknown interpreted text role "method".
...
```

My method docstring is:

```
... 
This method uses :method:`~app1.forms.other_method` to do other thing.
...
```

How can I cross-reference this `other_method`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Sphinx Domains](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects) a method of an object should be cross-referenced using `:py:meth:`

The correct docstring would be:

```
... 
This method uses :meth:`~app1.forms.other_method` to do other thing.
...
```

Note: Python domain is the default so `:py:meth:` is the same as `:meth:`